# Cucumber-JVM, Kotlin and Spring Configuration causing No Default Constructor error

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a project with Cucumber for java set up, (actually using Kotlin but this is just using java under the hood). 
It uses spring for DI and a setup that works fine with the following configuration:

```
package com.cucumberproject.projectA.hooks

import com.cucumberproject.projectA.profile.ProfileManager
import com.cucumberproject.projectA.profile.EnvironmentProfile
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean

class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun profileManager(): EnvironmentProfile {
        return ProfileManager().getEnvProfile(
            "clientId",
            "clientSecret",
            TokenUrl,
            AuthorisationUrl);
    }
}
```

```
package com.cucumberproject.projectA.hooks

import io.cucumber.java8.En
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration


@ContextConfiguration(classes = [AppConfiguration::class])
class SetupSteps : En {

}
```

```
import com.cucumberproject.projectA.hooks.*
import com.cucumberproject.projectA.profile.EnvironmentProfile

import io.cucumber.java.PendingException
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario
import io.cucumber.java8.En

class FeatureSteps @Autowired constructor(private var profile: EnvironmentProfile) : En {

    private lateinit var scenario: Scenario

    @Before
    fun initialise(scenario: Scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario
    }

    init {

        Given("A certain state") {
            // code in here that works
        }
```

I am trying to create a new project with the same setup. It has access to the same AppConfiguration file, EnvironmentProfile file and SetupSteps file as they are pulled in as a dependency.

```
package com.cucumberproject2.projectB.stepdefs

import com.cucumberproject.hooks.AppConfiguration     //original project 
import com.cucumberproject.hooks.SetupSteps           //original project 
import com.cucumberproject.stepdefs.ProgramSetupSteps //original project

import io.cucumber.java.Before
import io.cucumber.java.PendingException
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario
import io.cucumber.java8.En

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

class OtherFeatureSteps @Autowired constructor(private var setupSteps: SetupSteps) : En {

    private lateinit var scenario: Scenario

    @Before
    fun initialise(scenario: Scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario
    }

    init {
        Given("Some other state") {
            // code here
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to run the cucumber tests with the old project, everything works fine. When I try with the new project I get this error:

```
Apr 08, 2020 11:36:07 AM io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime run
SEVERE: Exception while executing pickle
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Error creating bean with name 'com.cucumberproject2.projectB.stepdefs.OtherFeatureSteps': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cucumberproject2.projectB.stepdefs.OtherFeatureSteps]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.cucumberproject2.projectB.stepdefs.OtherFeatureSteps.<init>()
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:110)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:63)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:27)
Caused by: io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Error creating bean with name 'com.cucumberproject2.projectB.stepdefs.OtherFeatureSteps': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cucumberproject2.projectB.stepdefs.OtherFeatureSteps]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.cucumberproject2.projectB.stepdefs.OtherFeatureSteps.<init>()
        at io.cucumber.spring.SpringFactory.getInstance(SpringFactory.java:213)
        at io.cucumber.java8.Java8Backend.buildWorld(Java8Backend.java:62)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.buildBackendWorlds(Runner.java:165)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:61)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$null$2(Runtime.java:102)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:258)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$3(Runtime.java:102)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:204)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1359)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:103)
        ... 2 more
```

I haven't got much experience with using Spring and the original project was setup by someone else. Can anyone see what's going wrong? 
I've tried adding the `@ContextConfiguration(classes = [AppConfiguration::class])` to the top of the new steps file, which gets me a bit further and a different error message:

```
Apr 08, 2020 11:46:20 AM io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime run
SEVERE: Exception while executing pickle
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Error creating bean with name 'com.cucumberproject2.projectB.stepdefs.OtherFeatureSteps': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.cucumberproject.hooks.FeatureSteps' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:110)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:63)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

But honestly, I have no idea if this is the correct thing to do. Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you use [No-arg](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin) plugin in the old project? Or also it could be that Spring can't find `SetupSteps` bean. Probably in some place you have to declare where to scan for Spring components.

Comment: @sedovav I can't find it in our build.gradle files so I don't think so

Comment: @AimeeJones Cucumber-Spring uses field injection - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/spring. Not familiar with kotlin syntax but to me seems u r using constructor injection. Also cucumber-spring beans uses a SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE scope.

Comment: You're also mixing `cucumber-java` and `cucumber-java8` in the same class. There is no guarantee that will work well.